# How do you pass additional variables to a CarrierWave uploader in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I see this has been asked a few times over the years (eg [Upload path based on a record value for Carrier wave Direct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738700/upload-path-based-on-a-record-value-for-carrier-wave-direct), [Passing a parameter to the uploader / accessing a model's attribute from within the uploader / letting the user pick the thumbnail size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713628/passing-a-parameter-to-the-uploader-accessing-a-models-attribute-from-within)), but I'm convinced I must be overcomplicating this, as it seems like a very simple problem...

I have a very straightforward `Video` model that mounts an uploader:

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :file, VideoUploader
end
```

In the controller, I allow two parameters:

```
    def video_params
      params.require(:video).permit(:title, :file)
    end
```

In the actual `VideoUploader`, I seem to have access to a number of variables derived from the `:file` column using class builtins (eg `original_filename`), and I can process the file using ffmpeg parameters. However, I want the parameters to be conditional based on the `:title` string, and I have *no* idea how to scope it or access it. What is the absolute simplest way to make sure this variable is accessible to those methods?

Edit: here's the uploader code:

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
  include CarrierWave::Video
  case @title # not working
  when "tblend_glitch"
    process encode_video: [:mp4,
      resolution: "1280x960",
      custom: %w(-to 5 -vf scale=-2:720,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,spp=4:10,tblend=all_mode=average,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,spp=4:10,tblend=all_mode=average,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,spp=4:10,tblend=all_mode=average,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference)]
...
  end
  def full_filename(for_file)
    super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '.mp4'
  end
  def filename
    original_filename.chomp(File.extname(original_filename)) + '.mp4'
  end
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access the instance in the uploader using the `model` method.

You haven't defined `@title` — it's `nil`. You can create a conditional version with the following code.

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  version :tblend, if: :tblend_glitch? do # use a better version name
    process encode_video: [:mp4,
      resolution: "1280x960",
      custom: %w(-to 5 -vf scale=-2:720,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,spp=4:10,tblend=all_mode=average,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,spp=4:10,tblend=all_mode=average,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,spp=4:10,tblend=all_mode=average,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference,tblend=all_mode=difference)]
  end

   # rest of the code

  private

  def tblend_glitch?
    model.title == 'tblend_glitch'
  end
end
```

Ref: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#conditional-versions

Comment: I thought that would be it, but it comes back undefined...

Comment: @serilain undefined? Do you mean `nil`? Have you initialized the `Video` object with the title?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's my Python brain translating... Video gets initialized like this, which should include all of the params as far as I can see...

`def create   @video = Video.new(video_params)`

Comment: also, if I'm not being clear enough, the repo is here: https://github.com/axfelix/ffmpegOnIce

Comment: @serilain Can you add your uploader code (with the `model.title` code you have tried ) to the question?

Comment: @serilain Just updated my answer on how to generate a conditional version.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can access the `model` and its attributes from the uploader. However, it looks like the mounted uploader gets invoked before the other attributes are assigned.

For me it worked to create the model with the regular parameters first, and assign the attribute that has the uploader mounted (in your case `:file`) in a second step. Then I could read all `model` attributes correctly from within the uploader.

In your case that would be something like this in the **controller**:

```
@video = Video.new(video_params.except(:file))
@video.file = video_params[:file]   # Invoke uploader last to access the other attributes
```